# ionic ui-router resolve's result didn't show in the page

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router, angular-promise

Here is the code

**APP.js**

```
.state('app.aboutus', {
  url: '/aboutus',
  views: {
    'mainContent': {
      templateUrl: 'templates/aboutus.html',
      controller: 'AboutController',
        resolve: {
            leaders:  ['corporateFactory', function(corporateFactory){
                return corporateFactory.query();
          }]

        }
    }
  }
})
```

**Controller.js**

```
.controller('AboutController', ['$scope', 'leaders', 'baseURL', function($scope, leaders, baseURL) {

                $scope.baseURL = baseURL;
                $scope.showLeaders = false;
                $scope.message="Loading ...";

                $scope.leaders = leaders;

                console.log($scope.leaders);

                }])
```

**Aboutus.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="About Us">
  <ion-content>
      <div class="card">
            <div class="list list-inset">
                <div ng-repeat="leaders in leadership" class="item item-avatar item-text-wrap">
                    <h2>{{leaders.name}}</h2>
                    <h4>{{leaders.designation}}</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
      </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**db.json**

```
"leadership": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "name": "Human 1",
      "designation": "Chief Executive Officer"
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Human 2",
      "designation": "Chief Food Officer"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Human 3",
      "designation": "Chief Taste Officer"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Human 4",
      "designation": "Executive Chef"
    }
  ]
```

When I checked using inspect element - console tab in Google Chrome, the $resolved: has successfully changed from false into true, and every array contain the information per ID.

But, the data didn't show in the aboutus.html

Did I typed something wrong? or maybe I'm using a wrong method?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is likely that your `ng-repeat` syntax is incorrect. Where you have `leadership`, that should be the object/array you're referencing in your scope. So try changing it to this:

```
<div ng-repeat="leader in leaders" class="item item-avatar item-text-wrap">
     <h2>{{leader.name}}</h2>
     <h4>{{leader.designation}}</h4>
</div>
```

Comment: oh, you're right! After I make some adjustment on there, everything works fine, thanks!